# How to handle foreign key in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresql..I am creating a database which contains table  “user” with columns “Name”,”Sum”,”id”(which is a serial primary key)

I want to input data only in columns Name and Sum since id is a serial PK

The column “id” is a foreign key in another table “account”, so when I am trying to input data in the table it is telling me I am violating the foreign key constraint

Here is the code:

```
INSERT INTO public.”user”(“Name”,”Sum”)
VALUES (‘Tasneem’,400);
```

It is telling me

```
Insert or update on table “user” violates foreign key constraint “user_Sum_fkey”
Key (Sum)=(400) is not present in table account
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `user` is a bad choice for a table name. It's a reserved keyword and an internal function and thus requires double quotes to be used. But if you forget the double quotes you get many very strange errors. I strongly recommend you find a different name. As a rule of thumb: don't use double quotes in SQL. The create much more problems than they are worth it.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statements for **all** tables involved including the foreign key constraints.

Comment: Ok noted will change it

Comment: I don’t have the codes since i already created the tables a long time ago

Comment: If you are in pgadmin, browse to the table in the objects' tree, then right click on it, select script > Create script. That will be what we want to see for the 2 tables.